# Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, ubuntu

After a few Ubuntu updates this started happening. Whenever logging into this server, either by using the LDAP client or a local user, it takes a long time to get authenticated and log in.

/var/log/auth.log:

```
Jan 14 06:19:16 norwich systemd-logind[18114]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:19:41 norwich systemd-logind[18225]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:19:41 norwich systemd-logind[18225]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:19:41 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 14 06:20:06 norwich systemd-logind[18329]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:20:06 norwich systemd-logind[18329]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:20:06 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 14 06:20:31 norwich systemd-logind[18441]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:20:31 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 14 06:20:31 norwich systemd-logind[18441]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:20:56 norwich systemd-logind[18552]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:20:56 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 14 06:20:56 norwich systemd-logind[18552]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:21:21 norwich systemd-logind[18665]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:21:21 norwich systemd-logind[18665]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 14 06:21:21 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
```

The server is using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and:

```
Linux norwich 4.4.0-109-generic #132-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 19:52:39 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have already restarted the server with no effect.

Here's the journal log:

```
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: Failed to forward Released message: No buffer space available
Jan 15 13:01:03 norwich systemd[1]: Failed to forward Released message: No buffer space available
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd-logind[11142]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd-logind[11142]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jan 15 13:01:28 norwich systemd[1]: Failed to forward Released message: No buffer space available
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd-logind[11146]: Failed to enable subscription: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd-logind[11146]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jan 15 13:01:53 norwich systemd[1]: Failed to forward Released message: No buffer space available
Jan 15 13:02:18 norwich systemd-logind[11150]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out
Jan 15 13:02:18 norwich dbus[929]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out
Jan 15 13:02:18 norwich systemd-logind[11150]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out
Jan 15 13:02:18 norwich systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 15 13:02:18 norwich systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
```

Comment: can you provide more information? Is this an LDAP client? is the LDAP server running? Do you have any way to check if the services running properly or not?

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL This is a LDAP Client. Local users face the same problem. Seems to be a problem with systemd.

Comment: This is most likely caused by LDAP - if the host can't establish a connection to the LDAP server (networking issue / certificate issue / DNS issue) then logind won't startup - and logind is used by both local and LDAP users. IMHO it is a defect in the systemd design - I never encountered issues around this before systemd. Meanwhile you need to look at the LDAP connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to:

- /var/run and /run are not symlinked
- You have dbus version which is buggy, see https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95263 - this seems to be fixed in dbus 1.11.10 and also in some patched versions of 1.10.x (happens to me with dbus 1.10.24-12.el7_6, seems to have stopped with 1.10.24-13.el7_6, but might be a coincidence as well)